# How to debug Xamarin application on a Windows tablet from Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, uwp, remote-debugging

I built cross platform application using Xamarin, I can debug it for iOS and Android from Visual Studio, is there any way to debug same code for Windows tablet.

I tried remote debugging but my application never listed under Running App list.

Comment: You should add a UWP project in your xamarin.froms .And make your PC and tablet connected to the same WiFi network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to debug UWP apps on a remote device, you will have to [install the **Remote Tools**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/run-windows-store-apps-on-a-remote-machine?view=vs-2017#BKMK_download). This needs to be running so that the device is discoverable and available for debugging.

You can download the tools from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/run-windows-store-apps-on-a-remote-machine?view=vs-2017#BKMK_download). Consider going through the whole documentation page [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/run-windows-store-apps-on-a-remote-machine?view=vs-2017) if you face any trouble discovering the device then. There is also a troubleshooting section which might help.